# Sunspot SolrException: The field location_s does not support spatial filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, lucene, sunspot

I am trying to run this command as part of my solr search:

```
with(:location).in_radius(x, y, 50, :bbox => true)
```

I have defined this in my model definition:

```
location :location do
  Sunspot::Util::Coordinates.new(latitude, longitude) if self.latitude
end
```

I can run this command:

```
with(:location).near(x, y, :precision => 3)
```

However, **I can't run the in-radius search**, which is what I really need.

Here is the server log:

```
  SOLR Request (5.0ms)  [ path=#<RSolr::Client:0x00000006fc4fa8> parameters={data: fq=type%3ADispenser&fq=%7B%21bbox+sfield%3Dlocation_s+pt%3D29.7601927%2C-95.36938959999999+d%3D50%7D&start=0&rows=10&q=%2A%3A%2A, method: post, params: {:wt=>:ruby}, query: wt=ruby, headers: {"Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}, path: select, uri: http://localhost:8982/solr/select?wt=ruby, open_timeout: , read_timeout: , retry_503: , retry_after_limit: } ]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 293.3ms

RSolr::Error::Http - RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error
Error:     The field location_s does not support spatial filtering

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: The field location_s does not support spatial filtering
    at org.apache.solr.search.SpatialFilterQParser.parse(SpatialFilterQParser.java:86)
    at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:142)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:114)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:173)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1372)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252)

Request Data: "fq=type%3ADispenser&fq=%7B%21bbox+sfield%3Dlocation_s+pt%3D29.7601927%2C-95.36938959999999+d%3D50%7D&start=0&rows=10&q=%2A%3A%2A"
```

--> [**Link to schema.xml**](https://gist.github.com/funkdified/14e2e9502083c191b53c) <--

Comment: can you post the definition of location_s in the schema. It typically needs to be a LatLonType.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/funkdified/3b503314738b97ab19e8

Comment: The location_s schema does not seem to exist. Only the location, can you try renaming/copying the field to location_s to see if it solves? Not sure why sunspot is converting location field to location_s.

Comment: I see this might be overlapping `<dynamicField name="*_s" stored="false" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>` possibly clashing, try removing

Comment: can you also post the whole model class?

Comment: Ganesh, can you suggest an update to my schema file. I need the entry you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I can read from the Sunspot source, it appears that `location` fields do not support `in_radius`.

In the examples, [all calls to `in_radius`](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/search?q=in_radius&ref=cmdform) use `:coordinates_new`. It seems that [`:coordinates_new` is of type `latlong`](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/5488725cb2587973e7ff809f234eb437a76424f4/sunspot/spec/mocks/post.rb#L57) instead of `location`.

Does using `latlong` instead of `location` solve your issue?

Comment: Yes, it was the latlong thing.. which also required the new version of sunspot / solr to work properly.